# How to use a WebView to display an image

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to create a WebView to display an image.

But on the second/third start of the application `WebView` is empty on real devices.

When I comment out `//wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` then all is good and when in .http I am deleting `onload="resize(this);"` an app is starting with image every time too.

How to correct this. How to use `JavaScript` and don't to have empty `WebView`?

Maybe I need to save the cache after first initialisation?

```
public class TestwebViewimageActivity extends Activity {
private WebView wv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());  
    wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/4.html");
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**my .html** mast show image in full window:

```
<html><head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="myimage.png" onload="resize(this);" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function resize(image) {
    image.style['height'] = document.body.clientHeight + 'px';
    image.style['width'] = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';

    image.style['margin'] = 0;
    document.body.style['margin'] = 0;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help thinking you'd be better off using CSS than JavaScript to resize your image.

I made an example using the great background-size: contain; property that auto-scales the background so it fits within the div, I think this is what you were trying to achieve with your JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/4DNsL/

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String summary = "<html><body><div style=\"background:red; \"</div>
<img src=\"res/drawable/banner300.jpg\"/></body></html>";
mWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to manually resize the image? Just set the width of the image and let the webview adjust the height accordingly. It works perfectly for me.